# VisJs timeline style error

Tags: javascript, html, css, vis.js

I'm dynamically adding items to a visjs timeline, using the option {queue:true} and flush() to improve performance. To style the items I defined 3 classes in my CSS.
They are correctly applied, but sometimes they don't change the item color as specified. I tried remove the queue option, but the problem persists. The error can be seen on Firefox and Chrome (I'm on linux).
[The first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rjQp.png) shows the class item_ligado that should turn the item to green, but it's being drawn as red. If I scroll the image out of the screen and then back again it gets the correct color as seen on [the second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzmmR.png).

My css is defined as

```
.vis-item.timeline_ligado {
   background-color:#66CC00;
   border-color:#66CC00;
   color:#FFF;
}
```

I am calling redraw() after flush(), but it makes no difference if I remove it.

Comment: This question can be ignored, I noticed I was inserting two items with the same start and end dates, each with different CSS. Sometimes the timeline showed one and sometimes other.